# Update/Increment multiple MySQL columns in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have this query, which works...

```
UPDATE `contacts` 
       SET `calls_to`=`calls_to`+1 
  WHERE `contact_no` = '0412345678';
```

What I also want to do is add a value to the cost field. From my understanding, the way to do this would be...

```
UPDATE `contacts` 
       SET `calls_to` = `calls_to`+1, 
             `cost_to` = `cost_to`+0.25 
  WHERE `contact_no`='0412345678';
```

Obviously, as I'm posting here, it's not working as I would expect.

**--UPDATE--**

As requested, the table structure..

```
id                  int(255) auto_increment
contact_owner  varchar(255)
contact_no       varchar(11)
contact_name   varchar(255)
calls_to            int(255)
txts_to             int(255)
time_talked_to   int(255)
cost_to            decimal(65,2)
```

Comment: What is happening? The query looks ok.

Comment: Could you post your database schema? Also could you post the result of `SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contact_no='0412345678'`? As an aside, I believe it is good practice to always add a `LIMIT 1` to updates that you don't expect to affect more than 1 row :)

Comment: @mdma: My guess is that the `cost_to` is an INT data type, so the decimal that is added in the UPDATE gets truncated. I can't see what else it could be. ...and your answer was *so* not there.

Comment: @OMG - Agreed - I'd answered before your comment!

Comment: @OMG - I should have known running fast backwards would get me in trouble someday...  (really didn't see the comment. I think I posted before, but also made some typo edits afterwards, which now don't show up as separate edits.)

Comment: @mdma: You're supposed to use a slingshot orbit around the sun, and transparent aluminum!  Kids these days...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the datatype for `cost_to` is int or not.Also update the column if it's value is not null.

```
UPDATE `contacts` 
       SET `calls_to` = `calls_to`+1, 
             `cost_to` = `cost_to`+0.25 
  WHERE `contact_no`='0412345678' AND
          calls_to is not null AND
          cost_to is not null;
```

Comment: This seemed to work. Thanks :D

(Side note, I had to set the default for calls_to and cost_to to 0.)

Answer (score 1):

On first glance the query looks fine. What is the type of the `cost_to` field? Double check it's not an integral type, since you will then not get the result you are looking for. (As a test, add a larger value, say, 4 to cost_to.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your `calls_to` field as int and `cost_to` field as in different type, so only you didn't got the result.  Check the type of the field.

Answer (score 0):

Single-table syntax:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

Multiple-table syntax:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
```

For the single-table syntax, the **UPDATE** statement updates columns of existing rows in the named table with new values. The **SET** clause indicates which columns to modify and the values they should be given. Each value can be given as an expression, or the keyword **DEFAULT** to set a column explicitly to its default value. The **WHERE** clause, if given, specifies the conditions that identify which rows to update. With **no WHERE** clause, all rows are updated. If the **ORDER BY** clause is specified, the rows are updated in the order that is specified. The **LIMIT** clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated.

For the multiple-table syntax, **UPDATE** updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times. For multiple-table syntax, **ORDER BY** and **LIMIT** cannot be used.